# Background color WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

My problem is that my button has a background color for some reason, and I do not know why. I do not put the desktop background in the entire area of ​​the button.

[image]

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    hwndButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"Some static text",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW,
        25, 125, 300, 300, hWnd, 0, 0, 0);
}
case WM_DRAWITEM:
{
    //RECT r;
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (hwndButton == lpDIS->hwndItem) {
        SetBkColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(0, 255, 0));
        //FillRect(lpDIS->hDC,&r,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100,100,200)));
        SetTextColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(100, 0, 100));
        WCHAR staticText[99] = L"test";
        TextOut(lpDIS->hDC, lpDIS->rcItem.left, lpDIS->rcItem.top, staticText, 10);
    }
```

Comment: No links, just [mcve] please.

Comment: I can't understand what question you are asking

Comment: Fixed, bye bye :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code only draws as much of the button background as the text requires, use ExtTextOut and specify ETO_OPAQUE to fill the entire space. Either that or use FillRect to actually draw the button background and use ExtTextOut without ETO_OPAQUE to draw with a transparent background.

Comment: I fixed with WM_CTLCOLORBTN